# docker-compose up with error "Couldn't connect to Docker"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

start learning docker / docker-compose and after some tutorials I thought I have found a good one.

```
https://github.com/sprintcube/docker-compose-lamp/tree/master/config/php
```

After installing and preparing I did:

```
sudo service docker start
```

and

```
docker-compose up -d
```

but it failed with this message:

```
dev@terra-dev:~/Projekte/docker-compose-lamp$ docker-compose up -d
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

Where do I have to define the docker host? In my docker-compose file? Or somewhere else?

regards n00n

update: Result of sudo service docker status:

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-10-06 13:25:25 CEST; 9s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 2640 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 14
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─2640 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Okt 06 13:25:24 terra-dev dockerd[2640]: time="2019-10-06T13:25:24.087358085+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Okt 06 13:25:24 terra-dev dockerd[2640]: time="2019-10-06T13:25:24.087381826+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Okt 06 13:25:24 terra-dev dockerd[2640]: time="2019-10-06T13:25:24.092676335+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Okt 06 13:25:24 terra-dev dockerd[2640]: time="2019-10-06T13:25:24.732654311+02:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 17
Okt 06 13:25:24 terra-dev dockerd[2640]: time="2019-10-06T13:25:24.959702995+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Okt 06 13:25:25 terra-dev dockerd[2640]: time="2019-10-06T13:25:25.020225493+02:00" level=warning msg="failed to retrieve runc version: unknown output format:
Okt 06 13:25:25 terra-dev dockerd[2640]: time="2019-10-06T13:25:25.096346086+02:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=2d0083d graphdriver(s)=overlay2 vers
Okt 06 13:25:25 terra-dev dockerd[2640]: time="2019-10-06T13:25:25.103672560+02:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Okt 06 13:25:25 terra-dev dockerd[2640]: time="2019-10-06T13:25:25.148505614+02:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Okt 06 13:25:25 terra-dev systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Comment: It seems your Docker daemon is not running. What is the output of `sudo service docker status`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are not able to connect to docker daemon. Either You are not using the right permission or Docker daemon is actually down.

Use below command(If docker daemon is already running.):

```
sudo docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Thats it. Why do I have do use sudo for it, my user is member of docker group...

Comment: If you add user to group using something like `usermod -aG` or `adduser` you may need to relogin before the command takes effect.

Comment: @n00n Check step 3 of https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/. You need to make sure the system re-evaluates your group memberships.

Comment: vincent163 answer is works for me, if not solved, look https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4181